# Column names when raise a typeerror in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm comparing 2 dataframes by their row names and I want to get the name of the rows that don't match  example:

```
check = sum(df1.index!=df2.index)
if check:
    raise TypeError("Not Match")
else:
    print("All OK")
```

When the index don't match I  want to print the first instance of the row that didn't match.  I've tried using a print statement as shown below but it doesn't execute.

```
    check = sum(df1.index!=df2.index)
if check:
    print(df1.index)
    raise TypeError("Not Match")
else:
    print("All OK")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement -

```
df1.index != df2.index
```

Returns a numpy array of `bools`. Let's retain this for now. It may need a slight change to work -

```
m = df1.index.values != df2.index.values
```

To get the counts of `True` (non-matches) in `m`, call `sum` -

```
if m.sum():
    raise TypeError(...)
```

To get the first instance of no-match, index with `m`:

```
print(df1[m].iloc[0])
```

Thanks to MaxU, here's a nicer solution using `argmax` -

```
print(df1[m.argmax()])
```

Comment: `"I want to print the first instance of the row that didn't match"` - do you mean `print(df1[m.argmax()])`?

Comment: @MaxU Yes, I think that's a good option, certainly better than mine. Feel free to answer, and I'll delete :)

Comment: i just meant that i understood OP differently - i think they wanted to print a first non-matching row, not its index. Your answer is just fine. Feel free to use it please :-)

Comment: @MaxU Thanks again... yes I see I misunderstood. I needed to do something along the lines of `df1[m].iloc[0]`

Comment: Thanks Guys.  It appears that this line 'm = df1.index != df2.index' automatically generates a ValueError and ends execution without giving me a chance to print anything.  Is there a way around this?